# Using Xcode for an iPad app, how do I recognize and highlight a country on an image of a continent (not in MapKit)

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, shapes

I'm trying to make an iPad app where I can drag the name tag of a country onto a blank map (image) and place it .  How do I make it so each country (shape within the border) will be recognized and highlighted as I drag the name tag around the map.  This is an educational app and I do not plan to use MapKit.  I am using an image of a continent.

Since I'm fairly new to Xcode and Swift, I haven't yet seen a way to work with extremely complex shapes, such as the very unique borders of each country.  I'm thinking SpriteKit might be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using MapKit you would need to draw every possible country with SpriteKit and overlay them on your image, then use the zoom and placement to calculate coordinates to determine which one it is in. It would be much easier to use some third party library for something like this.